# Is it possible to mount a derailleur on this bike?

Tags: derailleur, dropouts

Is there a way to mount a derailleur on this bike?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why?   Is the IGH getting worn out and you see adding a derailleur as a way to retain some gears without the cost of replacing the IGH ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

Buy an adapter claw like [this one](http://harriscyclery.net/product/sunrace-rear-derailleur-adaptor-claw-963.htm) (e.g. [Sunrace SP550](http://www.sunrace.com/en/products/detail/sp550).):

[image]

The claw screws into the dropout, then you bolt on the derailleur as normal.

Alternatively, you can buy a derailleur with an integrated claw like several in the Shimano Tourney line (E.g. the Shimano Tourney RD3105; actually pictured, RD8153):

[image]

Note that you still have the issue of getting in a wheel with multiple cogs in the frame. This might require [spreading the frame](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#spreading), if its steel (not a good idea on non-steel frames).

As mikes and mattnz point out in the comments, you also have to add cable stops and/or cable guides to the frame to route the shift cable. Or, run full length housing and use zip ties.  Problem Solvers among others make clamp on ones, and Origin 8 sells some zip tie-based cable guides you can use instead. You'll need to do a bit of searching and work probably to get the right routing, but they make cable stops that clamp onto the chainstays, the top tube, bottom tube, etc. A shop should be able to sort you out with these things relatively quickly. Other options might be to braze/weld on some.

Comment: You also have the issue of installing cable stops on the frame.

Comment: @mikes - thanks for pointing that out. i've updated the answer

Comment: If you run a full length outer cable stops are not required.

Comment: @mattnz - good point.